# How do I fix a codec encode error while using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, encode, codec

I'm reading my CSV and doing a little data cleanup and I'm getting the following error...

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x96' in position 6193: character maps to undefined

If I comment out the `sort_values` or `drop_duplicates` functions the error isn't produced. How do I fix this error? I'm a beginner and have spent hours today trying to google an answer but I have nothing. Code below...

```
import pandas as pd

theData = pd.read_csv(r'my.csv', encoding='latin1')

theData = theData.drop_duplicates(subset=['BROADCAST','ARTIST','SONG','LABEL','ALBUM'])
epNums = theData['BROADCAST'].str[15:]
epNums = epNums.str[:3]
theData['ep num'] = epNums
theData['ep num'] = theData['ep num'].astype(int)
theData = theData.sort_values(by=['ep num'])

print(theData)
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using `encoding='latin1'`? have you considered converting the encoding to `utf-8`?

Comment: I’ve tried UTF-8, ascii and still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to only happen on my PC, as it works fine on my friend's Mac. But what solved the problem was by replacing `encoding=` with `engine='python`.